# transparent gif doesnt show transparency over background with gradient in css

Tags: gif, transparency

I have a GIF picture with transparency. When I place the picture in a regular HTML the transparency shows fine. But when I load the same picture as a logo in a PHP software, the picture doesn't show the transparency but a white background.

The only strange thing I find in the page on which I load the picture which doesn't show the transparency, it has a gradient color background in CSS. I don't know if it's related to the problem or not.

What reason could there be that the GIF shows the transparency in some pages and in other pages it doesn't? Whatever the reason is, what can I do to make it work where I need it?

Comment: can you provide a link or jsfiddle/jsbin?

Comment: @Pablo : Does the background have any color, i mean where the image is loaded?.. Try putting the image some place else with no background.

Answer (score 1):

> what can I do to make it work where I need it?

I would use a .png instead a .gif as logo you will probably load it through css
 
`(background: url(path/.png) no-repeat;` , I know it does not answer the why but solves the issue for sure.

If a .png is too big in your opinion use the online great tool it uses even [advanced lossy compression for PNG images and preserves full alpha transparency](https://tinypng.com/)